# Does HipHop for PHP support intl (Unicode) extension?

Tags: php, unicode, hiphop, intl

I'm considering moving my code on HipHop for PHP, but can't find an answer for the question whether or not HipHop supports intl extension, which is required for my code to process Unicode text.

Also, where can I find a list of HipHop's limitations in general?

Comment: On their blog: http://www.hhvm.com/blog/ . Intl listed there as "lacking for support", but I don't know if it is unicode-one.

Comment: I've tried HipHop and faced many issues. Generally was limited to PHP 5.2 features when I tested it a few months ago. If your reason for moving your codebase is performance I'd recommend trying Phalcon instead

Comment: "can't find an answer for the question whether or not HipHop supports intl extension", I don't know the answer, but just try running your code and see what happens. The new JIT based HHVM is easy to get started with.

Comment: There is some support for intl, but it's not complete yet, so better to run your code and see if it works.

Comment: So when I install the hhvm I don't need to install php5 nor any of its extensions, right ?